# Sort out results from CVS diff into one file using BASH

Tags: bash, cvs

I am trying to change my bash script so that it puts all the changes under each file, rather than repeating the same file name.

So I am doing a diff using this command:

```
grep Index ${logs}/${file_diff} | cvs -q diff -r $pTag $pathDir | sed -r 's/^.+\///' > ${logs}/${output_filename}
```

The above will display the results of the changes in the previous tag in `output_filename`. But the problem is with the `pathDir`.

The `pathDir` has changes in the same files but different paths for each subject:

so `pathDir` contains paths to

```
this/is/the/path/to/the/changes/for/apples

this/is/the/path/to/the/changes/for/bananas

this/is/the/path/to/the/changes/for/grapes
```

but within those paths the file name change.dat has all the changes.

Is there anyway I can change the grep to show all the changes for apples, bananas and grapes under just change.dat?

Currently it shows the changes as:

```
this/is/the/path/to/the/changes/for/apples/change.dat

{Apple changes here}

this/is/the/path/to/the/changes/for/bananas/change.dat

{Banana changes here}

this/is/the/path/to/the/changes/for/grapes/change.dat

{Grape changes here}
```

as the changes are in change.dat I want to merge them to just show the changes in `change.dat`.

Thanks,

Comment: Some basic notes on style -- `${foo}` doesn't buy anything over `$foo` when used as a standalone argument. What *does* have a large impact on safety of expansions is quoting -- `"$foo"` is always going to expand into one argument, whereas `$foo` or `${foo}` can be zero, one, or many.

Comment: ...also, is your initial `grep` actually doing anything at all? Since it reads input from the content on the left-hand side (pipelines being left-to-right), it never sees output from the `cvs diff` on its right, and can't interact with it in any way (since `cvs diff` doesn't, as far as I recall, read from stdin... which is the only connection between those two processes).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help, I'm really grateful. The grep I was using was displaying results from a diff but not the diff used in the pipeline. It was actually using the diff created in this file ${file_diff}. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm reading up on the below answer and testing it out in my script. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# the above shebang line MUST be #!/bin/bash, since we use features not in /bin/sh

exec 3>/dev/null                        # start out with FD 3 writing to /dev/null
while read -r; do                       # iterate over lines in the cvs diff
  if [[ $REPLY = "Index: "* ]]; then    # when we see a line starting with "Index: "...
    full_filename=${REPLY%"Index: "}    # ...extract the filename
    base_filename=${full_filename##*/}  # ...then extract only the basename
    exec 3>>"$base_filename"            # ...then open FD 3 to append to the basename
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" >&3          # ...then write the index line itself
  else                                  # for lines that don't start with "Index: "...
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" >&3          # ...write the line to the existing FD3
  fi
done < <(cvs -q diff -r "$pTag" "$pathDir") # do the above for the output from cvs diff
```

This will give you one output file per basename -- so `change.dat` in the current working directory when this script is run will contain changes from each `change.dat` in the repository, and every other basename in the repository will similarly generate a distinct output file. If you want to ignore any file not named `change.dat`, by contrast:

```
#!/bin/bash
# the above shebang line MUST be #!/bin/bash, since we use features not in /bin/sh

while read -r; do                       # iterate over lines in the cvs diff
  if [[ $REPLY = "Index: "* ]]; then    # when we see a line starting with "Index: "...
    full_filename=${REPLY%"Index: "}    # ...extract the filename
    base_filename=${full_filename##*/}  # ...then extract only the basename
  fi
  # print to stdout if and only if the current filename is change.dat
  [[ $base_filename = change.dat ]] && printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done < <(cvs -q diff -r "$pTag" "$pathDir") # do the above for the output from cvs diff
```

See [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more on this method of reading input line-by-line.

See [BashFAQ #073](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) for more on the string manipulation technique used above, or [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for a gentler introduction to string manipulation in bash generally.

See [the bash-hackers tutorial on redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#exec) for more on how we're using `exec` here (other parts of the page may be good reading as well).

Comment: sorry I'm having trouble locating where the ${logs}/${output_filename} is being generated. The outut.

Comment: @Raj, in the first case, you'd want to make it `exec 3>>"$logs/$base_filename"`. In the second, all output is consolidated to stdout.

Comment: sorry but there is not file being created at all from this. I've replaced this at the top: exec 3>>"$$logs/$base_filename". Not sure why it's not generating a file.

Comment: @Raj, don't change the one at the top -- change the one inside the loop. At the top, you don't know what the file being processed is yet, so base_filename is unset. I'm presuming that the `$$` in your version is a typo, not a legitimate representation of what you tried to accomplish.

Comment: Beyond that, `set -x` is your friend for debugging. I'm guessing that your code is never seeing an `Index` line (meaning that the `[[ $REPLY = "Index: "* ]]` test is never matching); inspecting the `set -x` output will explain why this is so.

Comment: I'm about to spend a day traveling (home from abroad), and so may not be available for more feedback for some time. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Activate_Bash.27s_Debug_Mode for details on `set -x`, or the page generally for debugging hints. If you're unable to track down the issue yourself, paste a sample with `set -x` output somewhere without ads (gist.github.com is good, likewise sprunge.us or ix.io), and I'll look at it if/when I have a chance.

Comment: this is great it works fine. The only thing I did want it to do though was instead of creating a seperate file for each was to put all the changes in one file, but I will work that out. Thanks for you help.